# Swift: firebase didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not work on some device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, remote-notifications

My code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("Message: \(deviceToken)")
}
```

On `iphone 8 plus` and `iphone 6` print device token but on `iphone 6s` not work

`iphone 8 plus` and `iphone 6s` version are `11.4`

As the result `iphone 8 plus` and `iphone 6` receive notification but `iphone 6s` not receive

My code :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        if((Messaging.messaging().fcmToken) != nil){
            AppDelegate.USERTOKEN = (Messaging.messaging().fcmToken)!
        }

        print("Message APP: \(AppDelegate.USERTOKEN)")

        return true
    }
```

Note : `print("Message APP: \(AppDelegate.USERTOKEN)")` work for all devices and print token.

Comment: it means that didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications method called. Check the error which is passed there as argument

Comment: **func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("failed to register for remote notifications with with error: \(error)")
    }**

Comment: @AndreyChernukha no, this method also not called

Comment: @Sh_Khan i have this method but not print anything `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        print("Message ID6: ")
    }`

Comment: add some additional code

Comment: @ComputerIm are you sure you are calling registerForRemoteNotifications?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha yes of course. by defualt user token print but not receive anything

Comment: @Anbu.karthik please check my question

Comment: see this once may be it helps you : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift